# Does log4j support symoblic link log file?

Tags: log4j

I am trying to use a symbolic link in the file attribute of log4j.properties.
Below is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=./abl-che-logs.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Here abl-che-logs.log is a symbolic link to dev/stdout.

But I am getting the below error:

[image]
The command I used to create the symbolic link

```
ln -sf /dev/stdout /home/theia/browser-app/abl-che-logs.log
```

Can you anyone help me with what changes are required to log4j.properties to support symbolic link?

If you are wondering why I am using a symlink to /dev/stdout please refer [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout)

Answer (score 0):

Having same problem lately, I tried this, which might help you:

`ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /home/theia/browser-app/abl-che-logs.log`

I was trying to have the docker file showing the logs in the same way you are doing but RollingFileAppender was rewriting the file and taking away the symbolic link since I had also a RolloverStrategy defined. To fix it you need to add this to your xml file:

`<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" followLinks="true">`

[Here](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/823/docker-application-containers-stdout-logging-elk-kibana) you can see how he did it and maybe give you some hints.